# Hide ticker text in notification using Notification.Builder

Tags: android, notifications, ticker

I'm trying to display an ongoing notification without the initial ticker text display. I was able to get this working with the older style Notification by setting ticker text to null in the constructor:

```
mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_playing, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

However, I noticed that instantiating a Notification this way is now deprecated, and the use of Notification.Builder is recommended instead. However, I cannot get the notification now to display without the ticker text, even when I set ticker text to null:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

CharSequence contentText = "contentText here";

Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

// The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
// notification
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, -1,
                launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_playing)
    .setLargeIcon(null)
    .setTicker(null)
    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)                 
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setContentText(contentText);

mNotification = builder.getNotification();

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

Is it just not possible to turn off the ticker display with the new Notification.Builder? Is so, that's unfortunate, since I won't be able to update from the deprecated code.

Edit - The code that finally worked:

```
mNotification = builder.getNotification();

mNotification.tickerView = null;

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it (that is, `setTicker(null)`). What happens with the above code? The ticker shows up anyway? What OS, device, etc?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, with the above code the ticker shows up anyway. I am testing this on an Asus Transformer TF101 tablet running Android 4.0.3 and a 10.1-inch Galaxy Tab running Android 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set the tickerView to null after builder. that works fine for me
Code like:

```
Notification notif = builder.build();
notif.tickerView = null;
mNotificationManager.notify(id, notif);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same behavior and only this way I get it fixed!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to include `.setTicker` at all, just leave it out like so:

```
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_playing)
.setLargeIcon(null)
.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)                 
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
.setContentTitle(contentTitle)
.setOngoing(true)
.setContentText(contentText);
```